# Variable variable names in R (how to call them)

Tags: r

I have several dataframes `df1` `df2` ... `df10`

How can I pack these dataframes into a vector?

```r
# Not this:
c(df1, df2, df3, ..., df10)
```

I've tried it with a for loop:

```r
dataframes <- c()
for (i in 1:10)
  dataframes <- c(dataframes, paste("df", i, sep = ""))
```

But this just gives me the names of the dataframes as characters instead of the objects themselves.

Comment: You should not have separate data.frames. Put them into a list when you create them. Anyway, you can fix that mistake with `mget(paste0("df", 1:10))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector isn't the right tool here. For your purpose you need another container-like structure called `list`. Suppose you have the names of your dataframes stored in a vector called `dataframeNames`. Otherwise, create it. The function `paste0` concatenates vectors without spacing and coerces all objects in the function-call to characters.

```
dataframeNames <- paste0('df', 1:10)
```

Now you need to store your dataframes in a list. This can be done via an `lapply`. This function applies a given function (in our case a function that takes a name of an object in the current environment and grabs it) to every element of a container-like structure (in our case the character-vector of names) and stores everything in a list.

```
dataframeList <- lapply(dataframeNames, function(nam) get(nam))
```

To access these dataframes as list-elements, you can call them by their name or by indexing via double-square brackets.

```
dataframeList[[1]] #returns the first dataframe
dataframeList[[7]] #returns the seventh dataframe
dataframeList$df7 #returns the seventh dataframe too
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a character vector you can use `paste0`.

```
paste0('df', 1:10)
#[1] "df1"  "df2"  "df3"  "df4"  "df5"  "df6"  "df7"  "df8"  "df9"  "df10"
```

To get the actual objects of these names in a list use `mget` :

```
list_df <- mget(paste0('df', 1:10))
```